# How to use chi-squared statistics to select features in multi-class classification in R

Tags: r, classification, feature-selection

I have 50k text records which has almost 20k features and 19 class labels. I want to do a multi-class classification in R. I know that for a binary classification, the table and formula below are the keys to calculate chi-squared statistics:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to use chi-squared statistics for feature selection in multi-class classification?

Comment: This question seems to have more to do with statistical methodology rather than programming. Perhaps it's a better fit for [stats.se].